# Запись большого количества строк из БД в xlsx phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

есть база данных в которой около 30ты тысяч строк, раз в день мне нужно выгружать эти данные в xlsx файл, перед записью в xlsx немного эти данные обрабатывать по мелочам, и того получается генерация xlsx файла в 30 000 строк и 25 столбцов.

Суть проблемы: используя php spreadsheet (до этого simplexlsxgen) можно единовременно записать только колок 16ти тысяч строк, если больше то сервер прекращает работу скрипта с известной ошибкой "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in".

Было принято решение записывать строки по частям, создать cron который будет каждые 2 минуты записывать по тысячи строк в файл. Происходит это так: скрипт открывает файл

```
 $inputFileName = 'export_data.xlsx';
 $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName);    
 $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
```

далее формирует данные для записи и сохраняет в этот же файл уже с дописанными строками

```
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$outputFileName = 'export_data.xlsx';
$writer->save($outputFileName);
```

Проблема состоит в том что как только количество строк в файле начинает превышать 18 000 он начинает так же выпадать в ошибку "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in".
я так понимаю это от того что слишком много времени тратится на открытие файла, извлечение из БД и запись в файл и суммарно это превышает лимит сервера.

Есть ли какой то способ записать такой большой массив данных в xlsx более эффективным способом?

Comment: А не разумнее ли прямо в MySQL выполнить то самое "немного эти данные обрабатывать по мелочам", и записать результат в CSV (SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE)? Excel прекрасно открывает CSV...

Comment: @Akina вы правы я оптимизировал запросы получив нечто вроде такого "SELECT gr.*, sp.* FROM tm_returns_gr gr LEFT JOIN tm_returns_sp sp ON gr.id = sp.store_num LIMIT ".$limits[0].", 1000" но даже такой запрос выполняется порядка 20ти секунд, я засекал - просто запрос и получений результата mysqli_num_rows

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать библиотеку https://github.com/box/spout,  она эффективно работает с большими XLS файлами

Comment: @lezhni спасибо попробую, мне просто хотелось уточнить реально ли на php генерировать такие большие файлы или от меня требуют чего то технически не реального и такое надо например на плюсах делать, ведь каждый язык был задуман для определенных вещей

Comment: @lezhni спасибо помогло, если вы конвертируете коментарий в ответ то помечу его как верным!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать библиотеку https://github.com/box/spout, она эффективно работает с большими XLS файлами